# Construct a logical formula with 3 judgments(P,Q,R), involving implication, disjunction exclusive and the conjunction...

Tags: logic, set-theory

Construct a logical formula with 3 propositional logics, involving implication, disjunction
exclusive and the conjunction, which will be a tautology and prove that it is so without i
use accuracy tables.

I'm new to discrete math, need a bit help with this question possible.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Hi John :) Can you supply some background on what you have covered so far in theory? It's not so easy to give hints and advice as long as it's hard to tell what the problem really is. Like what methods of proof are you supposed to use you think? How have you defined the connectives if not by truth tables? Regards..